# How to add a value to a database in Flask without using a form?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask and advanced web development so go easy on me. This is my first time using Flask and I'm still getting the hang of it. I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question so I'll explain what I mean.

Through tutorials I've figured out how to relay data and information through the use of an HTML `<form>` element in things like registering/logging in a user and switching pages back to the index for example.

In my case, I'm creating a solve timer website for speed solving the Rubik's Cube. I had finished the website with pure HTML/CSS/JavaScript, which of course only saves a current session, and doesn't save times to a database. Now I want to convert it to a Flask website.

What I would like to know, and sorry if this is really broad, is how to have my JavaScript function that handles the end of a solve, and originally just saved it to a local array, now save it to the SQL database. I'm using SQLite in development before I switch over to PostgreSQL or MySQL later on my web server.

I'll elaborate more if I you want me to. Thanks in advance.

EDIT
Here's what I've attempted so far, with info from different tutorials:

(I've removed anything that isn't relevant)

*JavaScript*

```
  //...
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", '/bgprc', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ time: time }));
  //...
```

`time` is a variable produced after the solve is done being timed, and is what I'm trying to send to the database.

*models.py*

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #...
    times = db.relationship('SolveTimes', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    #...
    def load_times(self):
        times = SolveTimes.query.all()
        return times

class SolveTimes(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    times = db.Column(db.Float, index=True, unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

*routes.py*

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    times = current_user.load_times()
    return render_template('index.html', times=times)
#...
@app.route('/bgprc')
def background_process():
    try:
        time = request.args.get('time',  0, type=str)
        t = SolveTimes(time, user=current_user)
        db.session.add(t)
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

And finally in *index.html* I try to load the times in a table based off of what was passed in *routes.py*

*index.html*

```
...
<ul id="solveTimes">
  {% for time in times %}
    <li>{{ time }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to write the HTTP request in JavaScript. Check out [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), a package that handles forms in Flask. You will be using it often when developing in Flask. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIJKdCIEXUQ&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=3) explains how to use it very well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've used Flask-WTF a little bit, but only for things with html `<form>` elements. I'm not using those here, so are you able to recommend a way to get that package to work in my scenario? Or alternatively, should I be using the `<form>` here?

Comment: You could hide the form, if you don't want to display it, setting its style attribute to "display: none". You can then populate it and submit it with JavaScript. There are several ways of doing this directly through JavaScript, like AJAX, but it would be much more work. Flask WTF is reliable, secure, and easy to use.